# How we get multiple column count(TOP) using MySQL single query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure like:

```
id  | ex_name | att_name 
10  | David   | sam G&G   
12  | John    | mark hol     
13  | John    | john b      
14  | Mark    | john c    
15  | David   | mark hol   
16  | David   | mark hol      
17  | Mark    | sam G&G     
18  | John    | john b      
19  | David   | sam G&G      
20  | John    | sam G&G
```

When I'm using below query:

```
SELECT att_name
     , count(att_name) as att_count 
  FROM `tablename` 
 group 
    by att_name 
 order 
    by att_count desc
```

Returns:

```
sam G&G = 4
mark hol = 3
john b = 2
john c = 1
```

I want top values of output i.e 
      sam G&G which is 4

Same with column ex_name it returns:

```
David = 4
john = 4
mark = 2
```

I want top values of the ex_name column which is David and John having count 4

What I want the final output like :

```
ex_name | att_name | ex_count | att_count
David     Sam G&G     4          4
John                  4
```

I'm also tried below query to fetch the output but in this case, I get ex_name and att_name is NULL.

```
SELECT a.att_name,b.att_name,max(a.ex_count),max(b.att_count)
FROM application_data
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ex_name,count(ex_name) as ex_count
    FROM application_data
    GROUP BY ex_name
) a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT att_name ,count(att_name) as att_count
    FROM application_data
    GROUP BY att_count
) b
```

It returns:

```
ex_name | att_name | ex_count | att_count
NULL      NULL        4           4
```

Can you help me out?Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to also tell us which version of MySQL you are using, as if you are using MySQL 8+, there might be some new methods of approaching your problem.

Comment: The query assumes there is a `att_count` in the data, the example data does not have it.. Assuming you forget to place the data here still the query should not even execute because it's not ANSI SQL you can't mix non aggregate column(s) with aggregate column(s) in the `SELECT` clause without using `GROUP BY` see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nUaMoFNtP4o2NMRr7YjXqU/1)

Comment: @RaymondNijland, In the second query I mentioned count(att_name) as att_count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to aggregate your table by some column, and then retain all group records which share the highest count.  One way to do this is to add a `HAVING` clause to your current query which asserts that the count for a group to be retained is the highest count from all groups.

```
SELECT att_name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tablename
GROUP BY att_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename
                   GROUP BY att_name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1);
```

### Demo